# Binary classification of time series data, using LSTM (Long Short Term Memory)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

First, let's talk about my dataset. My data is coming from a 3-axis accelerometer (2Hz). Every data point is annotated 0 or 1 (Binary Classification problem). Dataset is imbalanced (class "0" -> approximately 66%, class "1" -> approximately 34%), So my dataset is left-skewed. Another property of my dataset is that annotation is continuous (ex. annotation goes for 0000...00 and then 111...11 and again 000...00 and again and again). My total dataset contains 1,91,302 data points.

I have tried 1D-ConvNet on my dataset to random shuffle (although the dataset got temporal sequence), I got pretty good results, validation accuracy: 81.5% and F1-score: 80.2%.

The problem happened when I wanted to prototype the **Many-to-Many LSTM model** [Andrej Karpathy blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/). My plan is to implement FIFO(First In, First Out) data structure to give input to the LSTM model. For example:

1st Input: [[1st data], [2nd data],...[n data]]    Annotation: [[1st data annotation], [2nd data annotation],...[n data annotation]]
2nd Input: [[2nd data], [3rd data],...[n+1 data]]   Annotation: [[2nd data annotation], [3rd data annotation],...[n+1 data annotation]]
... data will be flowing like this.

The final shape of the data is as follows:(Please Note that data is split into train-test without shuffling)

```
X_train shape:(142000, 128, 3)
y_train shape:(142000, 128, 1)
X_test shape:(47500, 128, 3)
y_test shape:(47500, 128, 1)
```

My LSTM model will be returning `return_sequences=True` in every layer. As the dataset is contious `stateful=True` will be given to the layers so that they are a continuity of the memory cell state [link-LSTM-layer-keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/). The last layer of the model contains `TimeDistributed` layer of Keras [link-TimeDistributed-layer-keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/).

This prototype of the model is always outputting the same `loss`, `accuracy`, `val_loss` and `val_accuracy`. I have checked the output of the last layer, the model is predicting always between 0.2-0.4 probabilistic output. I have tried 3 **loss functions**, `Adam`, `RMSprop`, `SGD`. and also tried turning the **learning rate** and changing the model depth. Everything gives the same output means everything is predicted as **class 0**.

Keras code of my LSTM model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation="tanh", batch_input_shape=(500, 128, 3), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation="tanh", batch_input_shape=(500, 128, 3), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=256, activation="tanh", batch_input_shape=(500, 128, 3), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=256, activation="tanh", batch_input_shape=(500, 128, 3), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=512, activation="relu")))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")))
model.summary()
```

Model Summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (500, 128, 128)           67584     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (500, 128, 128)           131584    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (500, 128, 256)           394240    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (500, 128, 256)           525312    
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (500, 128, 512)           131584    
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (500, 128, 1)             513       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,250,817
Trainable params: 1,250,817
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Model compile and training:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    shuffle=False,
    epochs=NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,)
```

Model Training Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
284/284 [==============================] - 50s 175ms/step - loss: 0.6833 - accuracy: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.6683 - val_accuracy: 0.6351
Epoch 2/10
284/284 [==============================] - 50s 175ms/step - loss: 0.6014 - accuracy: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.6695 - val_accuracy: 0.6351
Epoch 3/10
284/284 [==============================] - 50s 175ms/step - loss: 0.5940 - accuracy: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.6764 - val_accuracy: 0.6351
Epoch 4/10
284/284 [==============================] - 44s 156ms/step - loss: 0.5936 - accuracy: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_accuracy: 0.6351
Epoch 5/10
284/284 [==============================] - 45s 158ms/step - loss: 0.5882 - accuracy: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.6814 - val_accuracy: 0.6351
```

Also please note that I have trained in the various architecture of LSTM for almost 100 epochs and the same pattern continues. I have been stuck here for about 7 days, any inside into the problem will be highly helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try with metrics=["mse"]. I try it before. Even classification problems, we can use mse for the metric. My performance is improved from 0.5 to 0.73. The mse is used to get optimal gradient descent. For example, the label is 1. mse is 0.44. the parameters will change a little. If we use accuracy, 0.44 is 0, and the weights are updated more.

Comment: Isn't `metrics` just for performance measures? To my knowledge this is not considered to calculate the gradient.
Regarding the problem: I would start with a single LSTM layer. Having four of them consecutively leads to very complex temporal behavior that can be very hard to train. In my experience this often requires extensive parameter tuning.

Comment: changing `metrics` shouldn't do any good! The main problem might be the model is not learning anything!

I have tried using 1 and 2 layers of LSTM. The output is the same. @Chillston

Comment: Okay, another guess would be to check the data? Is it properly normalized/scaled?
Maybe try to add `recall`, `precision` and/or `auc` to your metrics to gain a bit more insight what exactly the model is doing wrong.
Also why do you set `stateful=True`, your application with the 1D Conv already showed that you model does not need a larger time horizon, right? Using stateful can potentially mess up your gradient.

Comment: Yes, the data is scaled properly. `accelerometer_data = input_frame.to_numpy() / MAX_GRAVITY`. As the dataset is continuous that's why I have used `stateful=True`. Have used another model without stateful. Output was the same :(

Comment: And did you set shuffle to True when you used non-stateful model?

Comment: @SafayetKhan - I know it has been a while since this post, but, were you able to resolve this issue? I am stuck in a similar situation.